# Hyperlink inside share action sheet text

Tags: ios, swift, uiactionsheet

I am trying to create `actionSheet` with share functionality. I have `NSMutableAttributedString` which contains String and should have link in it. But for some reason if you share it, it displays as regular text if I am trying to share it with **iMessage**. Is it even possible to do it or I am doing something wrong?

For other sharing communities like email, it displays it as link.

This is the attributed string:

```
let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Want to learn iOS? You should visit the best source of free iOS tutorials!")
attributedString.addAttribute(NSLinkAttributeName, value: "https://www.hackingwithswift.com", range: NSRange(location: 19, length: 55))
```

I am passing it into the activity(Yes, the example is taken from hackingwithswift :D):

```
let textToShare = [ attributedString ]
let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: textToShare, applicationActivities: nil)
```

Comment: I have one solution I dont know wether it is best or not but you can add textview in your actionsheet,and then fill textview's text with attributedString with attribute nshtmltextdocumenttype, because textview automatically takes hyperlink.

Comment: @Tarvo I am also facing this problem. Did you get any solution for this?